# Declare yearly data in read.zoo

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to read in yearly data with gaps using the `read.zoo` function from the `zoo` package. I am having some trouble finding the `FUN` that declares the data to be yearly data. The data set is located [here](http://data.is/U5605W).

The function call I am trying is

```
tsGDP <- read.zoo("us-gross-domestic-product-192919.csv", sep=",", format="%Y", 
 regular=FALSE, header=TRUE, index.column=1)
plot(log(tsGDP))
```

This works fine, but it chokes when I try to plot the ACF of the series

```
> acf(tsGDP)
Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object
```

[This R-list posting](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-January/185414.html) seems to indicate that this is because I am not declaring yearly data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Without data , it is hard to reproduce problem. 
But , from the documentation of **acf**

*By default, no missing values are allowed. If the na.action function passes through missing values (as na.pass does), the covariances are computed from the complete cases.*

why not to try with

```
 acf(x = tsGDP, na.fail = na.pass)
```

Comment: I have linked to the data in the question.